# Искусственный интеллект для игры в крестики-нолики

Tags: delphi, искусственный-интеллект

Я ещё нуб в делфи, я хочу создать ИИ (искусственный интеллект) для игры крестики-нолики, что бы ИИ мог запоминать тактику противника и в следующий раз смог сыграть вничью или даже победить противника!

Comment: В случае крестиков-ноликов на поле 3х3 принципиально разные варианты игры перебираются вручную :-) И оптимальный алгоритм можно построить в легкую. Учтите, что примерно половина вариаций - симметрично отраженные. А вот 5x5 и бОльшие поля - тут, да, нужно думать.

Answer (score 3):

самый простой ИИ глубиной 2 хода (сгодится для любой подобной игры):
сперва пишем функцию, которая проверяет, есть ли выигрышная ситуация на доске (3 подряд крестика или нолика)

делаем неполный перебор, глубиной в 2 хода:

1. цикл по всем возможным ходам (проверяем - если выигрышная ситуация - делаем этот ход и выходим из цикла - ура, мы выиграли!).
2. вложенный цикл по всем возможным ходам противника (если в результате хода противника у него получается выигрышная ситуация, то отмечаем этот ход как плохой и сразу переходим к следующей итерации цикла 1.)

в результате работы этого алгоритма получится массив из возможных текущих ходов, среди которых надо будет выбрать один и сделать ход. 
можно всегда выбирать тот, который не приводит к проигрышной ситуации.

можно доработать алгоритм и еще проверять ваш ход на то, сколько перспективных вариаций он порождает.

в случае игры крестики-нолики (3х3) сколько порождает линий с 2 крестиками. для эого просто написать еще функцию.

Насколько помню игру крестики-нолики, единственный серьезный вариант выиграть - сделать "вилку". Это такой ход, когда получается 2 линии с 2 крестиками, причем противник не может перекрыть их одним ноликом.

Проверить, получилась ли "вилка", никаких проблем нет.

---

у меня одноклассник писал игру - "футбол" на клеточном поле. Если кто не знает, что это такое: берется лист бумаги в клеточку, рисуется футбольное поле и нужно делать ходы. можно ходить по ребрам и диагонально, можно "отталкиваться" он уже нарисованной точки.

Полный перебор он естественно не делал. А был придуман такой алгоритм, как я описал выше. А алгоритм поиска наиболее удачного хода был такой: 
во-первых, никогда не делать ход, вследствие которого противник может сделать выигрышный ход.
во-вторых, делать самый длинный ход.

Победить такого компьютерного противника было очень не просто.

Answer (score 1):

Для примера: [крестики-нолики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8), [описание алгоритма компьютерного игрока](http://my.elvisti.com/maximsht/xo/algorithm.html).

Comment: на том сайте написано, что нужно составлять дерево с 362880 листами, затем выбирать поддерево... это ерунда какая-то.
обычный перебор 2-4 уровня вложенности с проверкой на выигрыш/проигрыш/возможные удачные ситуации (вилки, выгодный размен фигурами и т.п.) - этого более чем достаточно для нормального ИИ.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь вам поможет статья [Интеллектуальные системы. Алгоритм поиска оптимального хода в игре Крестики-нолики](http://www.dokwork.ru/2012/11/tictactoe.html).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте нейронные сети для обучения программы тактике противника.